# JAVA - Object constructor does not accept parameters?

Tags: java, oop, parameters, constructor

I recently got into java, and I am currently running into a bit of a problem.

I have a simple class, that has 2 strings as members and 1 constructor method.
Here is my class :

```
class ErrorMessage{
public void ErrorMessage(String type, String message){
    this.type = type;
    this.message = message;
}

private String type;
private String message;
```

}

As you can see my default constructor takes in 2 strings and sets the corresponding data members.

My problem occurs whenever I try to actually call that constructor.
In my main function I have created a TreeMap out of a String and a TreeSet of my errorMessage class

```
TreeMap<String, TreeSet<ErrorMessage>> log = new TreeMap<>();
```

The problem is whenever I try to add new ErrorMessage objects to a given entry of my treemap, I get an error that my constructor does not accept 2 strings. (Check picture below)

[image]

It only lets me do it if I leave it empty like so:

```
log.get(projectName).add(new ErrorMessage());
```

Soo, I was wondering what I am doing wrong, so that my compiler does not recognize my constructor? 
Here is the full code :
http://pastebin.com/i76EYmm1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not correct constructor:

```
public void ErrorMessage(String type, String message){
    this.type = type;
    this.message = message;
}
```

... for compiler **this is just method that happens to have name same as class name**!

From docs:

> Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that they use the **name of the class** and **have no return type**

Correct constructor should look like this:

```
public ErrorMessage(String type, String message){
    this.type = type;
    this.message = message;
}
```

Remember: **No return type in constructors!**

Answer (score 3):

Defined your constructor as follows

```
public ErrorMessage(String type, String message) {
  // Codes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In java a constructor has no return type not even void. Remove void for it to be a proper java constructor.

```
public ErrorMessage(String type, String message){
    this.type = type;
    this.message = message;
}
```